# Start date for entering the US on a J-1 visa

Tags: uk-citizens, j1-visas

I am a British citizen and have applied for a J-1 visa as I will be a camp counselor in the summer. My camp dates are 2nd June to 27th August however I'll need to fly on 1st June.

I entered my intended arrival date as 2nd June, will I be allowed to fly out?

I haven't yet received my visa though and still need to go to the US Embassy for an interview.  I want to make sure that I have enough time to fly into the States. I don't want them to stop me at the border and say you can't enter until tomorrow!

Comment: Typically J visa questions are discouraged here, the appropriate site is the Expat forum at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ although I note yours is a short duration progra. USA visas unlike many other visas like the UK and Schengen visas are issued such that the validity dates start from the day of issue. Basically on the day it is issued to you, you're able to travel on it even if the dates of travel you provided hasn't come yet.

Comment: J-1 can enter up to 30 days before the start of the program.

Comment: @ZachLipton since US visas are valid from the date of issue it seems unlikely if not impossible for anyone to be in possession of a visa that is not yet valid.

Comment: @phoog Ack! Thank you. I was getting my US and Schengen visas confused.

Comment: @SheikPaul and phoog - whilst what you've said is correct, it's also not relevant.  The visa will be valid from the day of issue, so the person can indeed "travel", however they will NOT be admitted into the US in J-1 status unless their programs starts within 30 days.  As a UK citizen they would be allowed enter in WT (visa waiver) status, but then would need to leave the country and re-enter within the 30 days before the program starts.  As the question asker is only looking to enter a few days before, this is not relevant, but your comments are at best misleading.

Comment: @Doc You are absolutely right. Although some students have been allowed in earlier than 30 days, they were only allowed in at the discretion of the immigration officer and it should not be attempted.

Comment: @Doc the the question is about a plan to arrive *one* day early. My comment was a response to another that said "you can enter up to thirty days early provided your visa is valid" (I am paraphrasing because the comment has been deleted). The comment about visa validity is neither irrelevant nor misleading in that context.

Answer (score 2):

**[J-1 Visa Exchange Visitor Program](https://j1visa.state.gov/participants/common-questions/)**

**How long before my J-1 program starts can I arrive in the United States?  How long can I remain after my program ends?**

> You may not arrive more than 30 days before the program start date shown on your DS-2019.  Upon completion of your exchange program, you have a grace period of 30 days to depart the United States.